# Assembly Language Instruction Manual

Tags: assembly, x86

Is there a manual for all the assembly level instructions for different processors? A list and a brief description of what each instruction does. 
My main interest is x86, but other processors would be useful as well.

Comment: Intel and AMD have such manuals for each of their processors freely downloadable.

Comment: You can easily find instruction set references for most popular processor families by searching for "<name of processor family> instruction set".

Answer (score 1):

For x86 you'll be mostly interested in Volume 2 of the [Intel manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).